# What value does the t* point to

Tags: c++, pointers

I am looking into the pointers and I came up with code like that

```
class b 
{

}
class d

{

}

d* a = 0;

b *t = new b();

*t = * ( b* )a;
```

What does this declaration mean?
What value does t have?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`t` will still be pointing to the object created with `new b();`. `*t =` changes the value of what `t` points to, not `t` itself.

Your last line contains undefined behavior as you're derefenrencing a null pointer. Also, your cast is actually a `reinterpret_cast` in disguise, which is something you shouldn't do.